# How to save the checked row in gridview to sql database

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I'm using the `GridView`, as first column I have a `CheckBox` - by selecting this `CheckBox` it's row should be saved into the database:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grid_stock.Rows)
{
   c = grid_stock.Rows[i].Cells[0];
   b = c.EditedFormattedValue == null ? false : bool.Parse(c.EditedFormattedValue.ToString());

   if (b != true)
   { 
       c.Value = true;
       //here i am inserting the data to sql.,
   }
   else
   {
       c.Value=false;
   }
}
```

But here I am not getting inside the loop, its not properly checking the checked items in the GridView...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one ,

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grid_stock.Rows)
  {
   DataGridViewCheckBoxCell chk = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell) row.Cells[0];
   chk.Value = !(chk.Value == null ? false : (bool) chk.Value);            
  }
```

or you can get your check value by this way ,

```
 if (Convert.ToBoolean(chk.Value) == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Value Is True");
        }
```

Comment: Hello ZEY.,but here chk is showing all times TRUE only.,for unchecked rows also.,

Answer (score 2):

Here is solution for your problem:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grid_stock.Rows)
{
    var _value = row.Cells[0].Value;

    if (_value != null && !(bool)_value)
    {
       c.Value = true;
       //here i am inserting the data to sql.,
    }
    else
    {
       c.Value = false;
    }
}
```

Actually you was missing `.Value` for `row.Cell[0]`, Hence in variable `c` will hold `DataGridViewCheckBoxCell`, not value contain.

Comment: c=row.Cells[0].value., instead of this code i can use c=row.Rows[].Cells[0].value

Comment: @Sarvan Its look fine, Did you replace ur complete code with this code? Cell[0] has `.Value` property. Why should one use index `i` in `foreach` look?

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @Sarvan Ok ok, got you, I think you declare your variable `c` with DataGridViewCell,Right? Check edited code.

Comment: @AnkushMadankar: you could also write it as `c.Value = _value != null && !(bool)_value` +1. please do not ask for up votes brother...

Comment: @naveen No, we have already check `null` for `_value` so no need of checking again while assigning in `if` statement. Yes we need to check in else statement like u suggest

Comment: @sarvan And upvoting on stack is free infact if u upvote 40 times in day u get medal for it!! I never reach this number till now, so upvote whatever u like :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing a `foreach` loop with a `for` loop. It should be:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grid_stock.Rows)
{
    c = row.Cells[0];
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hello.,i want to check in the gridview,which are the rows is checked for checking purpose only i am usinmg FOREACH loop.

Comment: Ok. Use it like what I wrote. A better approach will be using `FindControl()` to determine the checkbox value.

Answer (score 0):

```
 int j = 0;

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in grid_stock.Rows)

            {

              bool vc = Convert.ToBoolean(grid_stock.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value);

                if (vc == true)

                {

                   //Here my inserting to sql db

                   j++;

                }

            }

                else
                {
                    j++;
                }
```